# Figuring out the running time and space of a program

Tags: performance, big-o

Is there a good tutorial to understand how one calculates the running time and space for a given piece of code? I am looking at these coding books and the questions tell the running time however there is no explanation of how it gets that. I know the basic concept of Big Oh but are there some basic rules or tricks to figure out the memory and space requirements?

I might not be looking at the right place but any help or a link to some helpful tutorial would be great!

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also: try Stanford's CS106B course. You can download recordings of lectures for free from iTunes U. Highly recommended :)

http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=11f4f422-5670-4b4c-889c-008262e09e4e

Answer (score 3):

Get [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844). It's all there.

They also produced video lectures of the part you are interested in: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-one/ Scroll down for the video.

Comment: Added a link with video lectures from the book.

Comment: Cormen & Co are far from being a "tutorial", I'm afraid: while technically it's all indeed there, it not an easy way to understand the concepts. Skiena is more practical; funny enough, even in SICP the concept of time and space is given very graphically and thus easier to grasp.

Comment: Great advice nevertheless, +1

Comment: serious things should be studied in a serious manner. Practical and funny materials are good for getting an initial grasp on the subject, but eventually you have to turn into the more boring stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The basic rules are, each operation takes `1`; you're trying to understand how many times you do anything. That is, a cycle will take exactly the number of iterations multiplied by its body's cost.

The memory is even easier: as you create structures, keep an eye on allocation. Plus each recursive call costs you *all* the local variables. That's it. Easy, huh?

As of online resources, try http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/video-lectures/ — you should be mostly interested in part 2, Asymptotic Notation.

Additionally, it's just about time to enroll to http://www.cs101-class.org/ and http://www.algo-class.org/ classes at Stanford, free and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

The big O gives you an idea of how time and memory requirement scale on a ideal machine. The resources required on an actual machine for modest amounts of data are best measured using a profiler.

Comment: it's so not true in so many ways... Profiler is indeed good, thus no downvoting, but...

Comment: e.g., the difference between O(n^2) and O(n ln n) is not something you need a profiler to spot. On the other hand, working on algorithmic complexity for a non-important part is a waste of time. It all has nothing to do with an ideal machine, there's no "best": these are two different tools for two absolutely different tasks.

Comment: You can look at O(n^2) and O(n ln n) but that gives you no idea of factors, and little indication how it behaves on a real machine for a modest/realistic size of data. If you have one algo which takes twice as long as another, you won't know which is is the first and which is the second.

Comment: If you're bitten by O(n^2) vs O(n ln n), you can stop worrying about exact factors. Starting at N around 1e7, I can say for sure that O(n^2) is a no go, and O(n^3) was dead long ago. The big-Oh notation makes it easy to rule out problems way before you even start coding. So yes, it gives you a good indication of how it behaves on a real machine. As of "twice as long", that's indeed the task for a profiler, because O(n) == O(2n). As I say, these are different tools for different tasks. There's no sense to declare one to be the best—you have to master both.

Comment: @alf: stuff is not always that simple. Just to make an example, in Operational Research, the simplex algorithm is usually preferred over asymptotically better algorithm when solving non-astronomically-large problems, due to the **huge** constants hidden by the big-Oh notation.

Comment: @alf, lets say you have an O(n ln n) algo which needs to use disk but an O(n^2) which fits entirely in memory. Similarly with in memory or in cache.  You are right that you need to understand time complexity, but when it comes to real programs which are more complex, you can beat a profiler with realistic data sets. O(n^3) vs O(n^2) will show itself in a profiler pretty quickly as well.

Comment: @akappa simplex method happened to be a textbook example for such a case, so by the time you get there, you already know about it. And you you think about it for a while, you'll find that the ideal machine and profilers have nothing to do with it: wall clocks will do just fine. I can add more examples, too: bubble (oh noes!) sort is often preferred on short arrays due to its predictability. Theoretically faster matrix multiplication is almost never used, as shaving the thousandths from the power is nothing compared with cache line expiration... When not to use a technique is important, too :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey see above. I think that sticking to one tool only, you rob yourself. Which is fine, as long as you do not preach the approach. "Modest amount of data" is important here, true. All the details are important, too. Still, I don't think "use a profiler" constitutes an answer, especially when OP says, he read about big-Oh but not sure how to calculate.

Comment: @alf, You have a point that it doesn't really answer the question, perhaps it should have been a comment.  Calculating big-O is good if you are mathematically minded.  However, I find many people don't understand them particularly well and calculating them from scratch is rather hard.  For example get() and put() for HashMap is often quoted as O(1), however this assumes you have a hashCode which never results in any collisions. (even a perfect hash can give you collisions) From tests I find O(ln ln n) is more realistic, but that is empirically determined!

Comment: Well, I see you point now. As a practical tool substitute for an admittedly hard technique, profiler can do. I don't like this approach, but it may well be practical. Sorry for a long discussion :)

Comment: @alf, You made some valid points.  I have a habit of trying to answer what I think people should be asking not literally what they do ask.  IMHO, Sometimes its the right thing to do, sometimes not.

Comment: @alf: but wallclocks tell you something about "what", but nothing about "why". For example, a profiler can tell you that one method is better than one another due to the lower cache miss count.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read some books just like MIT's "Introduction to Algorithms 2nd", Sanjoy Dasgupta's "Algorithms" or Sedgewick's "Algorithms in C"?